# Installing font package only once via command in file

Tags: fonts, install

I have a package that install the [all-the-icons-package](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el) automatically namely

```
(use-package zerodark-theme
:ensure t
:init
  (load-theme 'zerodark t)
  (zerodark-setup-modeline-format))
```

all-the-icons state that for the correct fonts I have to invoke

> M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts

How can I put this command into a file so that it is installed only the first time after a fresh Emacs

Comment: From what I see, `zero-dark` has `all-the-icons` as a dependency. So having `:ensure t` will install `zero-dark` if you don't have and as an effect `all-the-icons` will also be installed. Sorry but I don't quite understand the question...

Comment: the fonts are apparently not automatically installed in contrast to the actual all-the-icons package when installing the zerodark package. i have to install the fonts separately. But how do i do that if I dont want to invoke M-x every time I set up Emacs on a different machine?